# Ionic with Angular dynamic Table

Tags: html, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, html-table

I'm trying to make a table on an ionic + angular page, where when I add a record, it's automatically included in the table... this part is working, but when it's time to show, we see that a new line is showing, but it's too small and the table barely increases... you can help me... I know I'm doing something very wrong, but I'm not finding where.

The part that should increase is below

```
  <div style="overflow-x: scroll; min-height: 30%">
    <table id='listaDeLotes' style="min-width: 80%; height: 100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Bobina</th>
          <th>Peso</th>
        <tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let r of listaLotes; let rowIndex=index" (click)="excluir($event, rowIndex)">
          <td>{{r["codBobina"]}}</td>
          <td>{{r["qtdPeso"]}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Below the Html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Lotes do Pallet/Roll</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="addinvPage" scroll="true">
  <ion-grid class="addinv-container" style="min-height: 35%">
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center" style="height: 5%">
      <ion-col size="5">
        <ion-label>Filme</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="6">
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="dadoFilme" placeholder="Filme"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center" style="height: 5%">
      <ion-col size="5">
        <ion-label>Qtd Bob</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="6">
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="dadoQtdBob" placeholder="Qtd Bob"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center" style="height: 5%">
      <ion-col size="5">
        <ion-label>Largura</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="6">
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="dadoLargura" placeholder="Largura"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center" style="height: 5%">
      <ion-col size="5">
        <ion-label>Comprimento</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="6">
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="dadoComp" placeholder="Comprimento"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center" style="height: 10%">
      <ion-col size="5">
        <ion-label>Peso</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="6">
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="dadoPeso" placeholder="Peso"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  <div style="overflow-x: scroll; min-height: 30%">
    <table id='listaDeLotes' style="min-width: 80%; height: 100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Bobina</th>
          <th>Peso</th>
        <tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let r of listaLotes; let rowIndex=index" (click)="excluir($event, rowIndex)">
          <td>{{r["codBobina"]}}</td>
          <td>{{r["qtdPeso"]}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <ion-grid class="addinv-container" style="min-height: 10%">
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center" style="height: 10%">
     <ion-col size="12">
       <ion-button (click)="incluir()" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">Incluir</ion-button>
     </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  <ion-grid class="addinv-container" style="height: 10%">
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center" style="height: 80%">
      <ion-col size="6">
        <ion-label>Qtd</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="6">
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="qtdTotal" placeholder="Qtd" disabled="true"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-grid  class="coninv-container" style="height: 100%">
      <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center" style="height: 80%">
        <ion-col size="6">
          <ion-button (click)="adicionar()" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">Adicionar</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="6">
          <ion-button (click)="voltar()" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">Voltar</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Below the scss:

```
ion-content.addinvPage {
  --background: url('/assets/imgs/fundo-azul.jpg') no-repeat 100% 100%;
}

ion-grid.addinv-container {
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 80%;        
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;

}

form.addinv-form{
opacity: none!important;
}
  
#listaDeLotes{
  margin:0 auto;
  border:0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 30px darkgrey;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#listaDeLotes thead th{
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(37, 132, 187);
  color:white;
  
  padding:5px 10px;
}

#listaDeLotes tr td{
  width:80%;
  padding:5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  
  cursor: pointer; /**importante para não mostrar cursor de texto**/
}

#listaDeLotes tr td:last-child{
  text-align: right;
}

/**Cores**/
#listaDeLotes tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #eee;
}

table{
    margin:0 auto;
    border:0;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 30px darkgrey;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  
  table thead th{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgb(37, 132, 187);
    color:white;
    
    padding:5px 10px;
  }
  
  table tr td{
    padding:5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    
    cursor: pointer; /**importante para não mostrar cursor de texto**/
  }
  
  table tr td:last-child{
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  /**Cores**/
  table tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #eee;
  }
```

Below, the angular code, how was solicited (but this is working):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from '../app.module';
import { NavController, NavParams  } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import { Platform, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Location, formatDate } from'@angular/common'; 
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ConsInvPage } from '../cons-inv/cons-inv.page';
import { ServicosService } from '../servicos.service';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-inv',
  templateUrl: './add-inv.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-inv.page.scss'],
})
export class AddInvPage implements OnInit {

  headers: Headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
  testBaseURL;
  param: any;
  param2;
  token: any = null;

  captura: string;
  localiz: any;
  palletRoll: any;
  descPalletRoll:any;
  descLocaliz:any;
  dadoFilme: any;
  dadoQtdBob: any;
  dadoLargura: any;
  dadoComp: any;
  dadoPeso: any;
  loading: any;
  qtdTotal: any;

  resultados: any;
  retorno: any;
  VALUE1: any;

  listaLotes: any[] = [];

  regSel: any;
  
  constructor(public alertController: AlertController,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    private nativeHttp: HTTP,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private servicosService: ServicosService ) {
    
    this.captura = this.servicosService.getCaptura();

    this.testBaseURL = AppModule.getBase();

    this.param = ``;

    this.selecionar();

    //this.getDataNative();
  }

  selecionar() {

    var retorno: boolean = false;

    // mostra dados
    this.descPalletRoll = this.servicosService.getPalletRoll;
    this.descLocaliz = this.servicosService.getLocaliz;
    this.dadoFilme = "";
    this.dadoQtdBob = 0;
    this.dadoLargura = 0;
    this.dadoComp = 0;
    this.dadoPeso = 0;
    this.qtdTotal = 0;
  };

  async incluir()
  {
    const incBobina = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Inclusao de Bobinas',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'Bobina',
          type: 'text',
          id: 'codBobina',
          placeholder: 'Codigo Bobina'
        },
        {
          name: 'Peso',
          type: 'text',
          id: 'pesoBobina',
          placeholder: 'Peso (Kg)'
        }],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Confirmar',
          role: 'Confirmar'
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancelar',
          role: 'Cancelar'
        }
      ]
    });

    await incBobina.present();
    let result = await incBobina.onDidDismiss();

    if (result.role == "Confirmar")
    {
      this.listaLotes.push({codBobina: result.data.Bobina, qtdPeso: result.data.Peso});
      this.qtdTotal += 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show how you're adding the record/row, also maybe an image to show what it's looking like. This is impossible to diagnose with just the static HTML

Comment: this part is working, it's angular, I know because the table enlarges a tiny part, and when I touch the thin line that appears, the select trigger is triggered. But ok, I edited the text. and thanks for the help